# OpsCenter backup error

Tags: backup, datastax, database-backups, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I got the below error during my scheduled backup. My backup occurs on my server itself and not on S3. I am on Opscenter 5.2.2

[image]

This does not happen daily. Before this, it had happened during the first time when I scheduled the backup, and today this is the second time. Also the link shown in the image for troubleshooting is broken. Why does this occur & how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Are you intentionally backing up the system keyspace?

Comment: no i am not, i have 4 scheduled tasks for my 4 different keyspaces, none of them are system